# A correct expression for Hardness?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I'm interested in whether it's possible to express the hardness of a result in the following form.

1.For example: Suppose $A(n)$ is the class of graphs for which the minimum degree $\delta(G)\geq n/2$ where $n$ is the number of vertices. Then does it make sense to say e.g the maximum clique problem is NP-hard for the class $A(n)$?

Note, i'm not really interesting in whether the max clique problem is actually hard, just whether it makes sense formally to express a result in this way. The main reason i'm interested in this is because i'm expressing hardness for a class of graphs where the input of a graph is a parameter which defines the class.

2. Supposing the answer to question 1 is yes and it does make sense to express hardness in this form, is all that is required to prove hardness just a reduction (in the usual sense) which constructs a graph in which the degree of each vertex is larger than $n/2$?

I apologise if the question is poorly written, and i really appreciate any clarification on the issues!

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes- your formalization makes sense. Is $A(n)$ NP-Hard for an arbitrary fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$? I don't know.

2) A reduction from an existing NP-Hard problem $L$ to $A(n)$ would suffice. Note that for each instance $\omega \in L$, you must transform $\omega$ to a graph in $A(n)$. Furthermore, your transformation cannot take any string not in $L$ to a graph in $A(n)$.

> The main reason i'm interested in this is because i'm expressing hardness for a class of graphs where the input of a graph is a parameter which defines the class.

One formalization of the CLIQUE problem is as follows:

**INSTANCE:** Let $G$ be a graph and let $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

**DECISION:** Does $G$ contain a clique of order $k$?

In this manner, the CLIQUE problem is not restricted to a fixed clique-size. It can be easier to show NP-Hardness of a larger class of problem, which makes this formalization appealing (such as when reducing from CNF-SAT).

You may find a similar formalization helpful in your own work.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful comments they're much appreciated!! Could you elaborate on the following point "Furthermore, your transformation cannot take any string not in $L$ to a graph in $A(n)$". Do you simply mean the reduction not only maps an instance from $L$ to a graph in $A(n)$ but given a graph in $A(n)$ we can also find an instance in $L$ which is mapped to it?

Comment: The reduction need not cover all of $A(n)$. Formally, a reduction from $L \leq A(n)$ satisfies $\omega \in L$ if and only if $f(\omega) \in A(n)$. This applies to all $\omega \in L$.

Comment: Supposing my reduction only worked for a particular infinite sequence of values of $n$ would that still be sufficient to prove hardness?

Comment: Is that particular sequence of values NP-Hard? If not, the answer is no.

Comment: The reduction that i've created from a known hard problem maps to an infinite sequence of values of $n$. So does this count as saying the sequence of values is NP-Hard?

Comment: As long as you are mapping from the entire problem, then yes.

Comment: yes every instance from the original hard problem in $L$ is mapped to a graph in $A(n)$ however it does not hold for each $n$ but rather an infinite sequence of them meaning given any $n$ there isn't always an instance in $L$ mapped to it. So just to clarify this is enough to say the problem is hard for the class $A(n)$?

Comment: It is hard for $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A(n)$, the union of all $A(n)$ sets. In particular, $f(L)$ is NP-Hard (where $f$ is your reduction). We apply the identity transformation from $f(L)$ into $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A(n)$ to deduce that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A(n)$ is NP-Hard.

Comment: Ok then by that same logic if the reduction only worked only for finite $n$, that then also  proves that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A(n)$ is NP-hard?

Comment: That's what I said in my previous comment. :-)